# How to edit files in-place while performing operation on the values matching the searched pattern?

Tags: text-processing, scripting, sed, awk, date

Given a list files containing random text and many datetimes in ISO format in it (e.g "2012-07-02T10:47:24+02:00"), how can I find all these datetimes and add 2 hours to each one ?
Ideally a solution that takes into account the fact that a day is 24 hours would be great (i.e "02T23:15 + 2" should result in "03T01:15" and not "02T25:15") but in my case that's not a big deal. And let's ignore the possible timezone consequences, and consider this as a simple math operation.

I already know how to do this in Python for instance, reading all files line by line and replacing the line when datetimes are found but I wonder if there is a more straightforward way of doing this, with awk or sed maybe ?

Thanks!

Comment: imho no as these programs afaik don't have a time component, so adding something will produce the wrong result

Comment: If you don't need the hour wraparound, you can use `sed -i`. Since sed can not do math, you'd need 24 patterns, each matching a specific hour and replacing with specific hour + 2. However, if all your strings contain the timezone offset (+02:00) you could simply cheat and change the time zone. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's more a job for `perl` like:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -pi -e 's/\d{4}-\d\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d/
(Time::Piece->strptime($&,"%Y-%m-%dT%T")+2*3600)->datetime/ge' file1 file2...
```

Comment: Great ! That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you sir.